# Table is printed in reverse order using xepersian

Tags: tables, xepersian

I am using `xepersian` package and the tables are printed in reverse order. For instance when typesetting the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{Umathcode}{\let\Umathcode\XeTeXmathcode}{}
\@ifundefined{Umathchardef}{\let\Umathchardef\XeTeXmathchardef}{}
\makeatother 
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|r|c c c c c c|}
\hline
$t(s)$ & 0 &  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
$x(m)$ &  3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which has to lead to a table in which the first column from left is t(s) and x(m), instead I get this table in PDF output (which is exactly in reverse order):

```
5  4  3  2  1  0  t(s)
8  7  6  5  4  3  x(m)
```

Comment: I guess it's the desired behavior when the writing direction is right to left. However, adding `\setLTR` after `\centering` seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can say

```
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering\setLTR
\begin{tabular}{|r|c c c c c c|}
\hline
$t(s)$ & 0 &  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
$x(m)$ &  3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

to change the writing direction in the `table` environment. In case you have a caption below the table you probably have to revert the writing direction with `\setRTL`.

The change of writing direction is local, so it will be undone by `\end{table}`.

A tip: don't use `[h]` as the only position specifier for the table float.

Comment: you saved my life!

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I just wanted to add a tip. If you use the command `\setLTR` before the `\caption` table in the caption will be written in English but if you add that after that will be written in farsi.